# OS X - Load images from url with local cache

Tags: ios, image, macos, caching

I would like to download images to be shown in my OS X application from an url.
By the time i'm using a library that uses NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection to get the files, but the images are sometimes heavy and the view delays some seconds to load.

In iOS there are libraries that loads the images from a local cache and the process is instantaneous. Is there some library or way to do that in OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

It has a catogory on [UIImageView](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html) that should do what you need.

Its also a good library in general for HTTP.